# NSWindow textured gradient fill weirdness

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

Hey, I've got a textured NSWindow, and I'm seeing some strange behaviour with the way it gets textured. If I have an IKImageBrowserView in the window, then there is a full light to dark gradient in both the title bar and the bottom bar of the window, but if I hide the IKImageBrowserView and show my NSBox, then the gradient starts light in the top, and ends dark in the bottom bar. I think screenshots may describe the problem more accurately.

Alternatively, is there a way of placing an NSTextField and an NSProgressIndicator overtop of an ikimagebrowserview? They aren't visible when placed above the ikimagebrowserview for some reason.

[image]

Comment: If you hide the nsbox as well does the dark gradient go away?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue with inconsistent NSWindow textured/metallic gradients.

My findings, and a solution which will work for the above issue may be found in the responses to the following post:

[NSWindow textured background with NStextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795505/nswindow-textured-background-with-nstextfield/11482772#11482772)

Comment: This answer (and your other identical one) should really be duplicate flags and/or comments.